# Preserve hierarchy in JMESPath query

Tags: json, jmespath

When querying some document, I'd like to select items down in the hierarchy, but otherwise preserve the parent names in the structure. For example when querying aws database members, I can use:

```
DBClusters[].DBClusterMembers[].[DBInstanceIdentifier,IsClusterWriter]
```

To get from:

```
{
    "DBClusters": [
        {
            "DatabaseName": "bazbar",
            "DBClusterMembers": [
                {
                    "IsClusterWriter": false,
                    "DBClusterParameterGroupStatus": "in-sync",
                    "PromotionTier": 2,
                    "DBInstanceIdentifier": "foobar"
                },
    ...
```

To:

```
[
    [
        "foobar",
        false
    ],
    ...
```

But how can I get the following response instead:

```
{
    "bazbar": [
        [
             "foobar",
             false
        ],
        ...
```

I.e. for every cluster, extract the the `DatabaseName` as the key name for the list of members?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context

- Jmespath query
- How to generate a query that preserves nesting of objects
- How to generate a dynamic object key that comes from the value of another object key-value pair

### Solution

- http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#object-projections
- http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#list-and-slice-projections

### Example

> Assuming the following sample dataset ...

```
    {
        "dbclusters": [
            {
                "databasename": "alpha",
                "dbclustermembers": [
                    {
                        "isclusterwriter": false,
                        "dbinstanceidentifier": "foobar"
                    }
                    ,{
                        "isclusterwriter": true,
                        "dbinstanceidentifier": "doobar"
                    }
                ]
            }
            ,{
                "databasename": "bravo",
                "dbclustermembers": [
                    {
                        "isclusterwriter": false,
                        "dbinstanceidentifier": "foobar"
                    }
                ]
            }
            ,{
                "databasename": "charlie",
                "dbclustermembers": [
                    {
                        "isclusterwriter": false,
                        "dbinstanceidentifier": "foobar"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

> ... the following jmespath query ...

```
    @.dbclusters[].{"databasename":databasename
        ,"dbclustermembers":[dbclustermembers[*].isclusterwriter
        ,dbclustermembers[*].dbinstanceidentifier][]
        }
```

> ... produces the following result ...

```
    [
      {
        "databasename": "alpha",
        "dbclustermembers": [
          false,
          true,
          "foobar",
          "doobar"
        ]
      },
      {
        "databasename": "bravo",
        "dbclustermembers": [
          false,
          "foobar"
        ]
      },
      {
        "databasename": "charlie",
        "dbclustermembers": [
          false,
          "foobar"
        ]
      }
    ]
```

### Pitfalls

- this approach does not produce the database name as the object key as requested in the OP

  - As of this writing (2019-03-22), dynamic keys are not available in standard Jmespath
  - [related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310005/42223)