# Dynamic/computed keys in JMESPath?

Tags: javascript, arrays, higher-order-functions, computed-properties, jmespath

From ES2015 with [computed properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)/[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)/[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) you can do:

```
[{name: 'foo', age: 43}, {name: 'bar', age: 55}].map(
    o => ({[o.name]: o.age})).reduce((a, b) => Object.assign(a,b), {})
```

…and get:

```
{ foo: 43, bar: 55 }
```

How do I get this from JMESPath?

---

Attempt:

```
$echo '[{"name": "foo", "age": 43}, {"name": "bar", "age": 55}]' | jp [].{name:age}
[
  {
    "name": 43
  },
  {
    "name": 55
  }
]
```

Answer (score 7):

### Problem

- How to construct a Jmespath query that returns objects with arbitrary key-value pairs
- The keys need to be dynamic, based on the output of a jmespath filter expression

### Workaround

- As of this writing (2019-03-22), dynamic keys are not available in standard Jmespath
- However, it is possible to return a list of lists instead of a list of objects, and simply post-process that list of lists outside of jmespath

### Example

```
 [*].[@.name,@.age]
```

> Returns

```
[['foo', 43], ['bar', 55]]
```

Which can then be post-processed outside of Jmespath, if that is an option for you.

### See also

- [github issue about this exact use-case](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/152)

Comment: Oh that's interesting, it actually isn't support yet?

Answer (score -3):

To get this result precisely:

```json
{ "foo": 43, "bar": 55 }
```

You should use this query:

```
@.{foo: @[0].age, bar: @[1].age}
```

But as you can see I don't retrieve the keys `foo` and `bar` dynamically because I can't do it in JMESPath.