# How to conditionally select a property using JMESPath

Tags: jmespath

e.g., from the data below I need to select names based on the preference:

```
[
  {
    "first_name": "Waseem",
    "last_name": "Khan",
    "preferred": "first"
  },
  {
    "first_name": "Jawad",
    "last_name": "Hussain",
    "preferred": "last"
  }
]
```

should return to:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Waseem"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hussain"
  }
]
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't think dynamic key is something that JMESPath supports. Related: [*As of this writing (2019-03-22), dynamic keys are not available in standard Jmespath* – dreftymac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55310005/2123530)