# How to convert key's value from dictionary to a new key in JMESPath?

Tags: python, jmespath

How to achieve following using [JMESPath](https://safe.menlosecurity.com/https://jmespath.org/)?

Input:

```json
[
   {"letter": "A", "word": "Apple"},
   {"letter": "B", "word": "Ball"},
   {"letter": "C", "word": "Cat"}
]
```

Expected Output:

```json
[
   {"A": "Apple"},
   {"B": "Ball"},
   {"C": "Cat"}
]
```

I have tried the following, but, it does not work for key while it works for value:

```
[].{@.letter: @.word}
```

Fairly a simple requirement, should be a small thing I am missing here.

Comment: This is not possible in JMESPath, as explained in [Dynamic/computed keys in JMESPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236960/dynamic-computed-keys-in-jmespath)