# JMESPath to create a dictionary (map) out of Tags key and value pairs from AWS CLI output

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, jmespath

I am trying to extract a few properties of AWS EC2 instance using JMESPath. I just started learning JMESPath using [this useful guide](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#functions). But because my knowledge is limited, I was only able to get the output like below.

```
% aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,KeyName,LaunchTime,State.Name,Tags[].[Key,Value]]" --instance-ids i-123456789101123
[
    [
        "i-123456789101123",
        "r5.8xlarge",
        "My_EMR",
        "2022-12-19T16:11:42.000Z",
        "running",
        [
            [
                "tag-key-1",
                "tag-value-1"
            ],
            [
                "tag-key-2",
                "tag-value-2"
            ],
            [
                "tag-key-3",
                "tag-value-3"
            ],
            [
                "project",
                "my-project"
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Ideally, I would like to format the output using JMESPath like below.

```
[
    [
        "i-123456789101123",
        "r5.8xlarge",
        "My_EMR",
        "2022-12-19T16:11:42.000Z",
        "running",
        {
            "tag-key-1": "tag-value-1",
            "tag-key-2": "tag-value-2",
            "tag-key-3": "tag-value-3",
            "project": "my-project"
        }
    ]
]
```

I have tried a bunch of different JMESPath expressions like below, but none of them seem to work. I'd greatly appreciate any suggestion. Thank you in advance!

```
# JMESPath statements that I've tried so far (actually there are more, but these are the 'promising' ones that I tried, but failed to work)

% aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,KeyName,LaunchTime,State.Name,map(Tags[].Key,Tags[].Value)]"
% aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId,InstanceType,KeyName,LaunchTime,State.Name,map(Tags[].Key,Tags[].Value)]"
% aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId: InstanceId, InstanceType: InstanceType, KeyName: KeyName, LaunchTime: LaunchTime, StateName: State.Name, Tags[].Key: Tags[].Value}"
% aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[].Instances[].{InstanceId: InstanceId, InstanceType: InstanceType, KeyName: KeyName, LaunchTime: LaunchTime, StateName: State.Name, Tags[*].Key: Tags[*].Value}"
```

Comment: is using `jq` instead of JMESPath an option? I remember that transposing values the way you want was a little easier in jq. But it has been a while.

Comment: JMESPath cannot generate dynamic keys for a JSON, sadly. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236960/dynamic-computed-keys-in-jmespath

Comment: Thank you both. I'll try out `jq` instead.